# default constructor that has the option to take in a parameter?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have 1 constructor have the option of being a default constructor if a parameter is not passed in.

Example, instead of having 2 constructors, where 1 is the default constructor and another is a constructor that initializes numbers passed in, is it possible to only have 1 constructor that if a value is passed in, set that value to a member function, and if no value is passed in, set the member function to a number.

example:

WEIGHT.H file:

```
   class Weight
{
public:
    Weight() { size = 0; }
    Weight(int a) : size(a) {}

    int size;
};
```

MAIN.CPP file:

```
int main(void)
{
  Weight w1;
  Weight w2(100);
}
```

I've been working on different school projects and they all require to have different types of constructors, and i'm wondering if there is a way to only have it once so it saves time. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Search up "default arguments".

Comment: And if you stay with your current default constructor, it is generally a better practice to initialize all member variables in the initialization list. Therefore `Weight() : size(0) {}` is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a constructor parameter may have a default argument, just like other functions can.  If all of the parameters of a constructor have default arguments, the constructor is also a default constructor.  So, for example,

```
class Weight
{
public:

    explicit Weight(int a = 0) : size(a) { }

    int size;
};
```

This constructor may be called with a single argument or with no arguments; if it is called with no arguments, `0` is used as the argument for the `a` parameter.

Note that I've also declared this constructor `explicit`.  If you have a constructor that may be called with a single argument, you should always declare it `explicit` to prevent unwanted implicit conversions from occurring unless you really want the constructor to be a converting constructor.

(If you aren't familiar yet with converting constructors or implicit conversions, that's okay; just following this rule is sufficient for most of the code you'll ever write.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible as suggested by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10890440/1040374) but as you know if you are not defining the Default constructor the compiler would take over the definition part if you have not provided any constructor definition. 
Its not an issue as such but its a better practice to define the Default constructor for proper initialization of values.

[Google C++ Style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Default_Constructors#Default_Constructors) also recommends it.

Comment: A default constructor will only be implicitly declared if there are no user-declared constructors, even if none of the user-declared constructors is a default constructor.